# Tinymce, and openmanager when upload media file types more than one mb cause Error: Upload folder not correctly configured

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, tinymce

I'm using codeigniter and in php.ini file i have :

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M; 
Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

but when i upload media files with tinymce, and open manager that is bigger than 1 mb error `Error: Upload folder not correctly configured` occur and i can't upload. for any help thanks.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,openmanager,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,visualblocks",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,lioniteimages,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,visualblocks,|,openmanager",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    //FILE UPLOAD MODS
    file_browser_callback: "openmanager",
    open_manager_upload_path: '../../../uploads/',

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "<?=base_url()?>assets/js/tiny_mce/examples/css/content.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "<?=base_url()?>assets/js/tiny_mce/examples/lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "<?=base_url()?>assets/js/tiny_mce/examples/lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "<?=base_url()?>assets/js/tiny_mce/examples/lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "<?=base_url()?>assets/js/tiny_mce/examples/lists/media_list.js",

    // Style formats
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
        {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
        {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
        {title : 'Table styles'},
        {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
    ],

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    },

  menubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "media",
  media_live_embeds: true
});
```

Pictures, audio with less than 1 mb and video with less than 1mb can be upload.
and my upload directory structure is:
`wamp
    ---www
       ---my_project
          ---assets
            --- js
               ---uploads
               ---tinymce`

Comment: i works for smaller files? can you set max_file_upload to 500?

Comment: @Thariama yeah but what cause this?

Comment: @Thariama No changes occurred

Comment: add the your upload coding or screenshot . because your upload path is worng

Comment: @jones post your code how you installed tinymce

Comment: @Ilan Hasanov pictures,video and audio with less than 1mb, is uploading

Comment: @VairaMuthu pictures,audio and video that are less than 1 mb can be uploaded, but in large file size has problem